# Trigger only when state changes from true to false

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a boolean stored in local storage and I need a function to run only when the local storage is changed from true to false. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: You've to provide a code or any work you've done even if its not working with much more context provided than that in order to get an answer, Take a look on [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the function when you change the local storage

Comment: can you edit and share a quick code snippet how you would do it? :)